# database created but not the table

Tags: android, sqlite

Android studio - by using SQLite database created but table doesn't.

Desn't matter what I've tried the table does not created.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myDb= new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "person.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");
    }
```

I didn't get any error, but i don't know what I'm doing wrong that only DB is created without the table.

Comment: Did you try by uninstalling the app from the device so the database is deleted and rerun?

Comment: Also why create the tables in the app? Just deploy a prepared DB with your app

Comment: uninstalling the app didn't solve it, I'm still getting DB without table inside.

Comment: Check your manifest for this line: `android:allowBackup="true"`. If it exists change it to: `android:allowBackup="false"`, uninstall the app and rerun.

Comment: I've changed it to android:allowBackup="false" , uninstalled app but still - only DB , what I'm doing wrong? should it be so complex??

Comment: How are you determining that the table has not been created?  I ask because I copied your code into a new project & launched the app, and was able to verify that the table person_table exists (though is empty).

Comment: I exported the file person.db which located under databases directory, and opened it on SQLite manager and also on db browser for SQLite, in both of them I didn't able to see the table's columns.

Comment: Huh...[this](https://imgur.com/a/aAtvi0b) is what I see in DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: Very Strange!!! 
Your person.db file is about 4KB?

Comment: i just now notice that onCreate function is not being called (by adding a Toast within the funcion) any idea what could be the reason? i have SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, it's 4KB.  Note that onCreate in SQLiteOpenHelper class will only be called the when the DB is installed, so you'll only see that toast if you uninstall the app from the device, then reinstall it (as forpas suggested)

Comment: If you uninstall your app, then change the onCreate of your MainActivity to look like [this](https://pastebin.com/msiDZLWE) and reinstall, what is the size of person.db?

Comment: i can't see the toast inside the onCreate in SQLiteOpenHelper  also after uninstalling the app and reinstall it, on the other hand i can see after that the DB is created under data directory. so i'm very confused here. Michiyo, this is my code:
MainActivity:
```public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb= new DatabaseHelper(this);

    }
}
```

Comment: ```public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "person.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";
    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context= context;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Toast.makeText(context,"constructor called3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: ```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {

            Toast.makeText(context, "onCreate called1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");
            Toast.makeText(context, "onCreate called2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (SQLiteException e){
            Toast.makeText(context,""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Any idea? :( whatever I've tried to do i still getting the db without the table

Comment: How can i send the person.db file to someone just for checking if the table exists within? 
Maybe i just can't see it with my "DB Browser for SQLite" tool ...

Answer (score 0):

I have found my ridiculous mistake: I exported to my PC only the person.db file without the  two other files ending with -shm and -wal.